# C - algorithm for transforming binary into decimal - doesn't work

Tags: c, binary

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;
int x;

scanf(" %c %c %c %c %c",&c1,&c2,&c3,&c4,&c5);

if (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 !='0' && c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 !='1'){
    printf("Not a binary number!");

    }

if (c1=='0' && c2,c3,c4,c5=='0' || c2,c3,c4,c5 =='1'){

    c5 = c5-48;
    c4 = (c4-48)*2;
    c3 = (c3-48)*4;
    c2 = (c2-48)*8;
    c1 = c1-48;

    x = c5+c4+c3+c2+c1;
    printf("%d",x);
    }

return 0;
}
```

So the code works for all numbers except when there's a 0(zero) typed as last(c5) character. When that happens I get "Not a binary number!". Where is my mistake? :)

I'm only getting started into C and programming so be kind with me heheh

Comment: `if (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 !='0' && c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 !='1'){` don't use drugs.

Comment: The condition of your first `if` statement evaluates to `c5 != '1'`, and everything else is ignored.  I suggest to turn on all warnings in your compiler, read them carefully, fix them, and come back if you still have questions.

Comment: Note: it is better to use `c3 - '0'` etc instead of `c3 - 48`.  It is much clearer what the transform is.

Answer (score 0):

first you cant take the binary digits at once, you have c1 to c5, what if the user enter the binary for 100, it will not work. so try something like this.
Try out this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int val, base = 1,cn, decinum = 0,rest;
int alert = 0;
printf("Please enter a binary number 0's and 1's: ");

scanf("%d",&val);

cn = val;   // saving it for printf
while(val > 0){
    rest = val % 10;

    if(rest == 0 || rest == 1) {
        decinum += rest * base;
        val /= 10;
        base *= 2;

    }else{
        alert = 1;
        break;
    }
}


if(alert){
    printf("Sorry not a binary number\n");
}else{
    printf("binary: %d ist %d",cn,decinum);
}


return 0;
}
```

> Please enter a binary number 0's and 1's:
>    01120100
>
> output:  Sorry not a binary
>   number
>
> Please enter a binary number 0's and 1's: 101
>
> Output:
>    binary: 101 ist 5

From the comments from cpatricio and Jonathan, you have large number for binary in mind like 8bits, and maximum 20 bits

```
int main()
{

unsigned long  val,cn, decinum = 0;
int rest, base = 1;
int alert = 0;
printf("Please enter a binary number 0's and 1's: ");

scanf("%lu",&val);

cn = val;  // save it for printf otherwise after the while loop is val = 0

while(val > 0){
    rest = val % 10;

    if(rest == 0 || rest == 1) {
        decinum += rest * base;
        val /= 10;
        base *= 2;

    }else{
        alert = 1;
        break;
    }
}


if(alert){
    printf("Sorry not a binary number\n");
}else{
    printf("binary: %lu ist %ld",cn,decinum);
}


return 0;
}
```

> probe
>   Output:
>   Please enter a binary number 0's and 1's:010101100001001011000
>    binary: 010101100001001011000 ist 705112
>
> Output:
>   Please enter a binary number 0's and 1's:0000001001011000
>    binary: 0000001001011000 ist 600

Comment: If I enter a 24-bit binary number, the `scanf()` will fail.

Comment: int - 10 bits, unsigned int - 10 bits, unsigned long int - 19 bits

Comment: @cpatricio you were right, i updated my answer now. and with unsigned long it can handle 21 and so on bits

Comment: Max of long int is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (19 numbers), max of unsigned long int is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (20 numbers), how can you handle 21 bits? (i can't change my last comment, but should be 19 bits for long int and 20 bits for unsigned long int)

Comment: @cpatricio i got you, you are right, i update my comments, thanks, but with arrays can handle more, as i said earlier